# Unobtrusive validation for numbered (repeated) fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I have a situation where I need to iterate through a small collection of query criteria and create a set of html fields for each.  I would like to get unobtrusive js validation working for them, but of course, the problem is that you can't use `@Html.XxxFor(m => m.FieldName)` because the field names need to be numbered - i.e.,

```
<input name="List[1].Category" />
<input name="List[1].Value" />

<input name="List[2].Category" />
<input name="List[2].Value" />
```

to get proper model binding and javascript behavior and whatnot.  Consequently, I have to use:

`@Html.Xxx("List[1].Category"...)` such that I don't get the unobtrusive validations emitted.

This all makes sense, but I'm wondering if anyone has found an elegant way to wire up unobtrusive validation in this scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a code snippet which demonstrates how to use the `XxxFor` methods and get name attributes which are indexed:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.List.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.List[i].Category)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.List[i].Value)
}
```

This would avoid needing to wire-up unobtrusive validation manually.